# Run script as admin but get the current user

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to make a script that keeps track of login/logout times of all thin-client users and writes them to a text file on the server. I will set up a task in Task Scheduler that runs a batch file which writes to a text file every time a user logs in/out. To write to a file at C:/ The script must be run as admin. This can be accomplished by selecting "Run with highest privileges" in task scheduler, and making sure it's run under an admin account.

However, I believe that when I use the %USERPROFILE% command, it will return the admin's username, not that of whoever just logged in/out. Is there a way to run the script with admin rights, but have some command to get the user that just logged in/out, triggering the task?

Comment: Don't run as admin.  Either create the file (as admin), then grant everyone permission to write to it or write it somewhere public that everyone can already write to.  It's an abomination to write things to the root (c:\) directory.  Any other company you see doing that is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, c: was mostly an example. Is there somewhere public that all users can access? I'm not aware of such a place

Comment: I knew you knew that.. you don't get 1500 points for nothing.  I myself would add "Everyone" or "Users" permissions to the ACL at the root of the Users\Public folder.  Should be harmless and recurse into any folder you want to write to.

Comment: how are you using %userprofile% in your script specifically? You can always `cd /d "%userprofile%"` in the script beforehand to get to the logged in directory, but if you are using it as a variable for writing, I guess it is a bit different

Comment: *Is there somewhere public that all users can access?* Of course. Public profile folder (or its subfolders, Documents, for example) - look for `%PUBLIC%` environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually is a bit easier than it seems. What we can do is scrape the current running tasks (in this case, explorer.exe) and pull out the current running user's information for you later to use as a variable.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "TOKENS=1,2,*" %a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" /FO LIST /V') do if /i "%a %b"=="%User %Name:" set _currdomain_user=%c
for /f "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=\" %a in ("%_currdomain_user%") do set _currdomain=%a & set _curruser=%b
```

By doing this first, you can now use `%_curruser%` to produce the username and `%_currdomain%` for the domain.

Test:

Open CMD as `admin` and enter the above code line by line. Now, type `@echo %_curruser%` and it will print the current users username.

From here on out you can user this instead of `%userprofile%`.

For example, after the above, you could do, say:

```
net user %_curruser% | findstr /B /C:"Last logon" >> C:\temp\%_curruser%.txt
```

This would print the current logged in user, date and timestamp from a shell running as admin to the C:\ drive and keep appending the data each time it was run with a filename unique to the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Narzard for the original code I just thought I'd list a correction & put the Batch file version.

If pasting line by line the "%User %Name:" just needs to be changed to "User Name:".
That full code is:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "TOKENS=1,2,*" %a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" /FO LIST /V') do if /i "%a %b"=="User Name:" set _currdomain_user=%c
for /f "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=\" %a in ("%_currdomain_user%") do set _currdomain=%a & set _curruser=%b
```

The code below is for saving into a batch file and displays the output.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "TOKENS=1,2,*" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" /FO LIST /V') do if /i "%%a %%b"=="User Name:" set _currdomain_user=%%c
for /f "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=\" %%a in ("%_currdomain_user%") do set _currdomain=%%a & set _curruser=%%b

echo Current Domain User: %_currdomain_user%
echo Current Domain: %_currdomain%
echo Current User: %_curruser%

rem Return to CMD prompt.
cmd /k
```

Both will allow you to use %_currdomain_user%, %_currdomain%, %_curruser% after they have run. Tested in Windows 10 & 11.